# How would I program the interface from the shortcuts gallery?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'd really like to program an interface similar to the shortcuts gallery as shown below:

[image: Link to image as cannot post due to lack of rep :(]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/ctsKhDB/IMG-5241.png))</sub>

So I'm thinking this would be a table view with custom cells and then some kind of paging view or collection view? Am I along the right lines?

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to achieve this UI you'd need to implement a UITableVIew with nested UICollectionViews.

Another approach would be to use a UIStackView with UICollectionViews.

Comment: No probs. Remember to upvote if the answer helped you out.